# C# / VS Project dependency is working in a project but not on another

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependencies

I have a project that has a dependency to an dll.

I have a sample project in console, that compiles and work fine.

When I add the same code, and same dependency on another project (winform if that matters) it throw the error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'xxxx' or one of its dependencies. The
>   specified module could not be found.

I've checked all possible VS parameters, all dependencies are there, it's both on the same:

- same VS 2017 IDE
- both 64bits
- same project properties.
- same solution properties.
- same files are present on the bin path (VS copies the dll to the path)

I can't find any difference between this two projects, however one works fine and not the other.

What other settings should I check ?

I can find if I open the csproj with notepad that the project that works has the line: `<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>`

and the other `<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>`

However I can't see this setting on VS; should I modify manually the csproj?

EDIT:

Modifying the .csproj as stated above did solve the issue, I guess that it force the compiler to compile in 32bit which would explain the missing dependencies. However on the project settings I did try using "Prefer 32bits".

I wonder if it's the right way to go modify manually this project file and if it shouldn't be done from the IDE instead..

Comment: Are you sure you are making all the required imports?

Comment: Check the config file for any assemblyBindings

Comment: There is a possibility that the dll you are referencing is dependant on some c++ library and visual studio is unable to find and copy such dependencies, you could try and copy all other libraries (if there are any) to your debug folder and maybe the library will then load just fine. Other possibility still regarding the same issue, is that first project changes Environment.Path to include path to where such library is.